# setsockopt() not returning error when setting a big socket recv buffer

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm testing the funcion **setsockopt()** with the below code and I'm getting a behavior I don't understand:
Below is the code snippet I'm running (*compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Qt 4.8.x*):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <QDebug>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/in_systm.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    int res;
    int bufferSizeByte = QString(argv[1]).toInt();

    qDebug() << "Setting socket buffer size to" << bufferSizeByte << "bytes";
    res = setsockopt( sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void*)&bufferSizeByte, sizeof(bufferSizeByte) );
    if ( -1 == res )
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR setting socket buffer size to" << bufferSizeByte << "bytes";
    }

    /*
     *  !! WARNING !!
     *  If we try setting the buff size over the kernel max: we do not get an error
     */

    int readValue = 0;
    unsigned int readLen = sizeof(readValue);
    res = getsockopt( sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void*)&readValue, &readLen );
    if ( -1 == res )
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR reading socket buffer size";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Read socket buffer size:" << readValue << "bytes";
        Q_ASSERT ( readValue == bufferSizeByte*2 );
    }


    return a.exec();
}
```

Basically I'm setting the recv buffer size for a socket, and reading it back to verify that the operation really succeded.
Setting the buffer size to a value withing the one configured in the Linux kernel (**/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max**) triggers the Q_ASSERT() as expecetd but I do not get the setsockopt error message.

For instance:

```
sergio@netbeast: sudo ./setsockopt 300000 
Setting socket buffer size to 300000 bytes  
Read socket buffer size: 262142 bytes  
ASSERT: "readValue == bufferSizeByte*2" in file ../setsockopt/main.cpp, line 43
```

**What I don't get is why the setsockopt() does not return an error**

Any clue?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're expecting `setsockopt()` to return an error, rather than just cap `SO_RCVBUF` by the value in `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max`? I think both behaviours would be reasonable, and can't find any documentation requiring one over the other.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying to understand. :) I'm asking the function to set a param to a specific value, as the value is not valid/out-of-range I was expecting an error.

Comment: You've tested the code, and have observed a behaviour that seems reasonable and doesn't appear to violate any specs. It is what it is. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @NPE probably you are right and I was just confused as the function did not acted as I would have expected. That also mean I'll have to read the value back to be sure the value set is really the one passed to the setsockopt()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementaiton of [`sock_setsockopt()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=sock_setsockopt) (which is what the system call `setsockopt()` ends up calling in the kernel) has a comment as to why setting a too large value does not incur an error. The comment indicates the reason is for compatibility with the original BSD implementation (and thus, for software written for BSD systems to be more easily ported to Linux):

```
            /* Don't error on this BSD doesn't and if you think
             * about it this is right. Otherwise apps have to
             * play 'guess the biggest size' games. RCVBUF/SNDBUF
             * are treated in BSD as hints
             */
```

Please note that if the maximum size is not exceeded when doing so (and if the minimum value has been satisfied) what is actually stored is double the value that was passed in to `SO_RCVBUF`. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

> **`SO_RCVBUF`** Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes. The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using `setsockopt(2)`, and this doubled value is returned by `getsockopt(2)`. The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` file, and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` file. The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.